# What type of flange is this and what's its application?

Tags: parts

[image]
I found this flange part in a box of assorted vintage MOPAR parts and can't figure out what its application could be. It sort of looks like a toilet flange for your household commode but I don't think it's that. I think it's some sort of automotive fitting.
It has a 4" OD and 2" ID -then a seat and drops to 2nd 1.4" inner ID. No identifying marks or stamping. It's a heavy steel part. Any idea what this might be and it's purpose ?
[image]

Comment: Do you have a picture of the other side?

Comment: Very well could be part totally off the subject of an auto part, since it was in a box of 50 plus mopar car parts this being only unidentified peice i thought it would be in right suitable category. Opinions welcome on or off subject matter thank you very much for input. Keeps my mind busy lol i love a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bearing carrier which sits off of the front of a heavy duty differential. Something like what I have circled in this picture (not exact one, but something very similar):

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that small side looks like it jams up into a seal.